# Check for $ _POST fields in a POST method form

Tags: login, mysql, wp-login-form

I'm trying to check if the username and password fields are present in the login form.

The problem is that the `if (!empty ($_POST))` code does not do this to me.

**UPDATE:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-btn'])) {

    //Sanitize POST Array
    $POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $username = $POST['username'];
    $password = $POST['password'];

    if(empty($username)) {
        echo "Username o email non inserita"; 
        return false;
    }

    if(empty($password)) {
        echo "Password non inserita"; 
        return false;
    }

    if($username && $password) {

        $login_array = array();
        $login_array['user_login'] = $username;
        $login_array['user_password'] = $password;

        $verify_user = wp_signon($login_array, true);
        if (!is_wp_error($verify_user)) {
            echo "<script>window.location = '" . site_url() . "'</script>";
        } else {
            echo 'Credenziali non valide!';
        }
    }
}
```

This is instead the login form that is on the same page, that is on the my-login.php page:

```
<form id="wp_login_form" action="/login/" method="post">
    <label class="my-username" >Username o Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="info-login" value="" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
    <label class="my-password" >Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="info-login" value="" placeholder="******">
    <label> 
    <input class="myremember" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever"><span class="hey">Remember me</span>
    </label> 
    <button type="submit" id="submitbtn" name="submit-btn" value="Login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Thanks a lot to those who will help me. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check username and password fields, try below code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-btn'])) {
    $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if(empty($username))
    {
        echo "Username empty"; return false;
    }
    if(empty($password))
    {
        echo "Password empty"; return false;
    }

    if($username && $password)
    {
        $login_array = array();
        $login_array['user_login'] = $username;
        $login_array['user_password'] = $password;

        $verify_user = wp_signon($login_array, true);
        if (!is_wp_error($verify_user)) {
            echo "<script>window.location = '" . site_url() . "'</script>";
        } else {
            echo 'Credenziali non valide!';
        }
    }
}
```

let me know if this works for you!

Comment: I entered your code but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: What kind of issue you are facing ? is there any errors occurred ? try to print print_r($_POST); inside  if (isset($_POST['submit'])). then check did you get posted data ?

Comment: Even during the first visit (ie before sending the form and the "submit" button), it is returned true to the following code: if (isset ($ _ POST ['submit'])) {

Comment: Effectively the array is printed without any content, namely: Array ([username] => [password] => [submit] => Login)

Comment: But it is normal in the case of the first visit

Comment: But what if there is nothing inside the array because it returns true to the following condition? if (isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: where did you paste above code? try to change name of submit button something like 'submit-btn-name' and change also in isset($_POST['submit-btn-name']))

Comment: Ok, I update the code in the application to make you see better.

Comment: Ok, now maybe it works, I'll let you know better soon.

Comment: okay. let me know

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, I succeeded, in the end it was like you said, I had to change the name of the submit button.

Comment: okay. you'r welcome!